# Why are these Hazelcast warnings appearing?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, hazelcast

I'm using Hazelcast to cache a JMS topic.

Everything works great up to a point. After about 30-40 minutes of runtime I start getting :

```
WARNING: [192.168.3.102]:5701 [devGroup] RedoLog{key=Data{partitionHash=-1465305045} size= 10, operation=CONCURRENT_MAP_PUT_IF_ABSENT, target=Address[192.168.3.102]:5701, targetConnected=false, redoCount=910, migrating=null
partition=Partition [186]{
0:Address[192.168.3.102]:5701
}
}
```

As much as I understood from reading dev forums these are Redo warnings meaning that Hazelcast can not connect to the specified instance `target=Address[192.168.3.102]:5701` to distribute the cache.

The odd thing however is that my configuration has only one node, which is the current server instance:

```
INFO: [192.168.3.102]:5701 [devGroup] 
Members [1] {
    Member [192.168.3.102]:5701 this
}
```

I'm using spring to configure it:

```
<hz:hazelcast id="hazelcastInstance">
    <hz:config>
        <hz:group
                name="devGroup"
                password="pass"/>
        <hz:properties>
            <hz:property name="hazelcast.merge.first.run.delay.seconds">5</hz:property>
            <hz:property name="hazelcast.merge.next.run.delay.seconds">5</hz:property>
        </hz:properties>
        <hz:network port="5701" port-auto-increment="true">
            <hz:join>
                <hz:multicast enabled="false" />    
                <hz:tcp-ip enabled="true">
                    <hz:members>192.168.3.102</hz:members>
                </hz:tcp-ip>
            </hz:join>
            <hz:symmetric-encryption enabled="true"
                                     algorithm="PBEWithMD5AndDES"
                                     salt="thesalt"
                                     password="thepass"
                                     iteration-count="19"/>
            <hz:asymmetric-encryption enabled="false"
                                      key-password="thekeypass"
                                      key-alias="local"
                                      store-type="JKS"
                                      store-password="thestorepass"
                                      store-path="keystore"/>
        </hz:network>
    </hz:config>
</hz:hazelcast>
```

I'm using Hazelcast 2.1, Spring 3.1 and Tomcat 7

So does anyone know why I'm getting the warnings ?

Thanks,

---

To answer the comments:

I use it like this:

```
final ConcurrentMap<K, V> cachedMap = getHazelcast().getMap(region);
cachedMap.putIfAbsent(key, value);
```

The `getHazelcast()` method returns the injected `HazelcastInstance` via spring (the one in the configuration above, I've checked the bean id and it seems ok).

---

Update 2.

There is a max size on the map added programatically:

```
final MapConfig mapConfig = hazelcast.getConfig().getMapConfig(region);

.... val is calculated here ....

mapConfig.getMaxSizeConfig().setSize(val);
```

`val` can not be less then 25000

I have tried without the size configuration however and I still get the warnings.

I also use `map.values(SqlPredicate(""))` to get values by date.

Comment: curious - which IP version is this - 4 or 6?  Also, I am assuming your map store implementation (is using one) is not being called at this point - is that correct?

Comment: It is being called. I'm storing whatever arrives on the JMS topic in a hazelcast map and successfully for some time. After 30/40 minutes I start getting the warnings and nothing is stored anymore.

Comment: Do you use any of IMap.lock(), IMap.lockMap() or Hazelcast transaction API? Or how do you use Hazelcast as a cache?

Comment: There are at most 10000 elements in the map at this time (usually around 8/9k).

Comment: @mmdogan I've updated the question. I don't use any `lock()` methods (not explicitly anyway, I'm not sure if its done internally in your API somewhere) and no I don't use the transaction API.

Comment: So you only use putIfAbsent() and maybe get(), right? Have you defined any max-size for map or all configuration related to Hazelcast is that you have posted above?

Comment: @mmdogan I have updated the question again.

Comment: @mmdogan Is it possible to get these warnings if the size calculation is wrong ?

Comment: Yes, if there is a max-size and no eviction is defined (eviction percentage or TTL or max-idle) then put operations will go into redo cycle until map size decreases under max-size to be able to insert new entry.

Comment: @mmdogan Yes that is the problem there is no eviction policy as I thought there is a default one :) Could you add an answer so I can accept it, thanks again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If there is a `max-size` defined for a map, `put` operations after map has reached to the `max-size` will go into `redo` cycle until map size decreases under max-size to be able to insert new entry.

Either you should remove some value from map or you should define some kind of eviction for that map. I mean you can define one or more of the followings;

- set an `eviction-policy` and `eviction-percentage`
- set a `time-to-live-seconds`
- set a `max-idle-seconds`

For more info see [Hazelcast Map Eviction](http://hazelcast.com/docs/2.1/manual/single_html/#MapEviction)